# How to get the BLOG template?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have Sharepoint 365 with Sharepoint Designer. I want to get the layout of the blog template (if possible in HTML). So i can customize it. Is it possible? Gr. P

Comment: Is there a reason you're relying on classic features in SPO?

Comment: I like the layout (design) of the blog. And I want to use it in a html-editor. Is there a way to capture the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, page template is saved on the cloud. With SharePoint Designer you can edit the page in advanced mode customize it with html code.